# How to increase the sampling rate of accelerometer to insanely high rates(2kHz) in android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, bandwidth

I am new to android. I am currently working on a project which needs me to measure the acceleration in the range of 1Khz.

From the BMA150  datasheet, I came to know that the maximum Bandwidth supported by it is somewhere near 1Khz.

But android doesn't support this bandwidth meaning it doesn't support very high sampling rate.

Can I increase the sampling rate to the said frequency, if power management is not a much of a concern? Maybe using native methods or something else?

Please help me.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you use [SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST) with [registerListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29)?

That gets data from the sensor as fast as android can possibly handle, so I imagine that's what you need to do. Because android uses the linux kernel, it's very difficult to create real time code.

If sensor_delay_fastest doesn't work for you, I don't imagine any native code you write will be much faster.

Comment: SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST gave me a maximum sampling rate of 110 Hz. And in Galaxy S4 I got around 180Hz. Are you very certain that I cant increase the sampling rate using native methods?

Comment: There is an example here on how to access the sensors using native methods http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html
But from what I've read in other stackoverflow threads, you get around the same speed.